# ignoring variable containing \ and multiple spaces usnig sed command

Tags: linux, shell, replace, sed

I have two variables,

```
first= new pool ser/@10.25.89.322 
second=ESX_10.2.3.4@10.52.33.21
```

i want to replace `ESX_10.2.3.4@10.52.33.21` with new pool `ser/@10.25.89.322` and also want to remove space before new word.

i have tried like,

```
sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\/\\\\}"/g"
```

and

```
sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\[ ]*/\\\\}"/g"
sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\ */ *\\\\}"/g"
```

I don't want to delete space ,just want to replace as it is(except space before "new").

Comment: i have treid like ,sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\/\\\\}"/g"

and sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\[ ]*/\\\\}"/g"

 also sed -i -e "s/${second}/"${first//\\ */ *\\\\}"/g" but didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
sed -i "/${second}/ {s:${second}:${first//\\/\\\\}:g ; s/ new /new /}"
```

It is removing the `space` in the first occurrence of `new` in the line after replacement.

Also, in the test below, double-quote were added:

```
$ first=" new pool ser/@10.25.89.322" 
$ second=ESX_10.2.3.4@10.52.33.21
$ sed -i "/${second}/ {s:${second}:${first//\\/\\\\}:g ; s/ new /new /}" mytestfile.txt
```

Comment: @Rishi super! consider to accept this answer formally then.